# How to structure a more complex Angular 2 application?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I am currently doing some research about Angular 2 and it seems like a lot of stuff changes so i wanted to rebuild a very common use case for my projects which looks something like this in Angular 1 to get the basics. But i stumbled upon some general questions about how to structure an Angular 2 application.

Let me give you an example how i solve this in Angular 1 right now.

- Basically it is not a single page application
- I just use directives to extend the DOM
- I do not need a routing

  ```
  <html ng-app=my-app>

    <head></head>
    <body>

      <my-autocomplete></my-autocomplete>

      <!-- Some server side code -->

      <my-navigation-menu></my-navigation-menu>

      <!-- Some server side code -->

      <my-main-app>

          <my-filter facet="one" />
          <my-filter facet="two" />
          <my-filter facet="three" />

      </my-main-app>
    </body>

  </html>
  ```

Now for the Angular 2 structure.

```
<head>
    <base href="/elasticsearch_frontend/">
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                myapp: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });
        System.import('myapp/main')
                .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</head>

<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>

<my-autocomplete></my-autocomplete>

    <!-- Some server side code -->

<my-main-app></my-app>
```

So the problem is the following:

It seems like that everything must be in the root of the application. I am more used to the Angular 1 style, where i used to use the directives to html tree. Now in Angular 2 i used the application component as a container to initialize my application.

1. So how could i structure my components to achive a similar result in Angular 2?
2. Might it be better to build two independent applications instead? One for the autocomplete and one for the main application, even if they share the same resources (currently via a service)

   3. I think that i do not need the template in the app.component.ts but if i remove it i will get this error: angular2.dev.js:23730 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Component 'AppComponent' must have either 'template' or 'templateUrl' set. Like said before, i just want to extend the DOM and initialize the directives in one place.

***main.ts***

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

***app.ts***

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';

import {SearchService} from './search.service';
import {CatalogComponent} from './catalog.component';
import {AutocompleteComponent} from './autocomplete.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',


    template: `
          <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    `,
    directives: [AutocompleteComponent],
    providers: [
        SearchService
    ]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public title = 'Elasticsearch Products Prototype';

    public queryParams : String[] = [];


    ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```

Comment: If you just want to extend the DOM, you can use Anguar2 directives which don't have `Template` or `TemplateUrl` means view.

Answer (score 1):

Micronyks is right : Components annotations (@Component) need a template or templateUrl attribute whereas Directices annotations dont - so consider using directives if you don't need html to replace.

About the structure, if you take a look at TourOfHeroes Google tutorial (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) you will find out that you need  :

- index.html with JS scripts included and xx-app tag
- main.ts file including bootstrap App component
- app.component.ts with template containing many xxx-xxx tags

And for your folder structure you can have a folder for your components, services, templates,..

Comment: This is what i read but the tutorial assumes that you have app.component.ts where you have to register the directives. So which would be an alternative place  to register the directives then if not using a component?

Comment: Think that for the moment it's better to follow structure provided by any tutorial you can find as Angular2 is not ready yet for production use..